# build.rs could not find native static library 'libvmaf, perhaps an -L flag is missing?

Tags: rust, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to generate bindings to libvmaf in rust. I have imported vmaf as a git submodule and my build step appears to be working as when I inspect the build artifacts I can see that files are getting generated as I expect.

Here's the specific error i'm getting:

```bash
cargo build
   Compiling libvmaf-rs v0.1.0 (/home/brandon/repos/libvmaf-rs)
error: could not find native static library `libvmaf`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?

error: could not compile `libvmaf-rs` due to previous error
```

Here's a tree of the build directory at a depth of four;
The static library i care about is at `./out/build/src/libvmaf.a`

```bash
.
├── invoked.timestamp
├── out
│   ├── bindings.rs
│   └── build
│       ├── build.ninja
│       ├── compile_commands.json
│       ├── doc
│       ├── include
│       │   ├── libvmaf
│       │   └── vcs_version.h
│       ├── meson-info
│       │   ├── intro-benchmarks.json
│       │   ├── intro-buildoptions.json
│       │   ├── intro-buildsystem_files.json
│       │   ├── intro-dependencies.json
│       │   ├── intro-installed.json
│       │   ├── intro-install_plan.json
│       │   ├── intro-projectinfo.json
│       │   ├── intro-targets.json
│       │   ├── intro-tests.json
│       │   └── meson-info.json
│       ├── meson-logs
│       │   └── meson-log.txt
│       ├── meson-private
│       │   ├── build.dat
│       │   ├── cleantrees.dat
│       │   ├── cmd_line.txt
│       │   ├── coredata.dat
│       │   ├── install.dat
│       │   ├── libvmaf.pc
│       │   ├── meson_benchmark_setup.dat
│       │   ├── meson.lock
│       │   ├── meson_test_setup.dat
│       │   ├── sanitycheckc.c
│       │   ├── sanitycheckc.exe
│       │   ├── sanitycheckcpp.cc
│       │   └── sanitycheckcpp.exe
│       ├── meson-uninstalled
│       │   └── libvmaf-uninstalled.pc
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── config.asm
│       │   ├── config.h
│       │   ├── liblibvmaf_cpu.a
│       │   ├── liblibvmaf_cpu.a.p
│       │   ├── liblibvmaf_feature.a
│       │   ├── liblibvmaf_feature.a.p
│       │   ├── libvmaf.a # Trying to link to this!
│       │   ├── libvmaf.a.p
│       │   ├── libvmaf.so -> libvmaf.so.1
│       │   ├── libvmaf.so.1 -> libvmaf.so.1.1.3
│       │   ├── libvmaf.so.1.1.3
│       │   ├── libvmaf.so.1.1.3.p
│       │   ├── libx86_avx2.a
│       │   ├── libx86_avx2.a.p
│       │   ├── vmaf_4k_v0.6.1.json
│       │   ├── vmaf_4k_v0.6.1.json.c
│       │   ├── vmaf_b_v0.6.3.json
│       │   ├── vmaf_b_v0.6.3.json.c
│       │   ├── vmaf_v0.6.1.json
│       │   ├── vmaf_v0.6.1.json.c
│       │   ├── vmaf_v0.6.1neg.json
│       │   └── vmaf_v0.6.1neg.json.c
│       ├── test
│       │   ├── test_cambi
│       │   ├── test_cambi.p
│       │   ├── test_ciede
│       │   ├── test_ciede.p
│       │   ├── test_context
│       │   ├── test_context.p
│       │   ├── test_cpu
│       │   ├── test_cpu.p
│       │   ├── test_dict
│       │   ├── test_dict.p
│       │   ├── test_feature
│       │   ├── test_feature_collector
│       │   ├── test_feature_collector.p
│       │   ├── test_feature_extractor
│       │   ├── test_feature_extractor.p
│       │   ├── test_feature.p
│       │   ├── test_log
│       │   ├── test_log.p
│       │   ├── test_luminance_tools
│       │   ├── test_luminance_tools.p
│       │   ├── test_model
│       │   ├── test_model.p
│       │   ├── test_picture
│       │   ├── test_picture.p
│       │   ├── test_predict
│       │   ├── test_predict.p
│       │   ├── test_ref
│       │   ├── test_ref.p
│       │   ├── test_thread_pool
│       │   └── test_thread_pool.p
│       └── tools
│           ├── vmaf
│           ├── vmafossexec
│           ├── vmafossexec.p
│           └── vmaf.p
├── output
├── root-output
└── stderr
```

Here's my build.rs file

```rs
extern crate meson;
use std::env;
use std::fs::canonicalize;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    //env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "1");
    let build_dir = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap()).join("build");
    let lib_dir = build_dir.join("src");

    let build_dir_str = build_dir.to_str().unwrap();
    let lib_dir_str = lib_dir.to_str().unwrap();

    meson::build("vmaf/libvmaf", build_dir_str);

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=libvmaf");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={lib_dir_str}"); // I believe this linker option is the problem

    // Path to vendor header files
    let headers_dir = PathBuf::from("vmaf/libvmaf/include");
    let headers_dir_canonical = canonicalize(headers_dir).unwrap();
    let include_path = headers_dir_canonical.to_str().unwrap();

    // Generate bindings to libvmaf using rust-bindgen
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        .header("vmaf/libvmaf/include/libvmaf/libvmaf.h")
        .clang_arg(format!("-I{include_path}"))
        .parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks))
        .generate()
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    // Write bindings to build directory
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
```

from what I can tell my `cargo:rustc-link-search` linker option is correct but I could use some guidance on why the linker can't find libvmaf

-- edit: i added a part to the build script that outputs lib_dir_str to stderr Also I canonicalized lib_dir before converting it to a string to see if that might help. In the build directory i can see a file with output from stderr. If I `ls` the canonical path to the part of the build directory where I expect to find (and link to) libvmaf.a I can see libvmaf.a as I would expect.
If I understand correctly the `cargo:rustc-link-search` option is equivalent to the `-L` flag in the compiler so I'm stumped on why if I inspect the directory, I can see the native static library I want to link to yet cargo somehow still can't find and link to libvmaf.

--edit Using `cargo build -v` i can see the verbose output of the build command. This way I can see exactly how rustc is being invoked

```
`rustc --crate-name libvmaf_rs --edition=2021 src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=5225226d4097e5e3 -C extra-filename=-5225226d4097e5e3 --out-dir /home/brandon/repos/libvmaf-rs/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/brandon/repos/libvmaf-rs/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/brandon/repos/libvmaf-rs/target/debug/deps -L native=/home/brandon/repos/libvmaf-rs/target/debug/build/libvmaf-rs-f8ca4c95356c61cf/out/build/src -l static=libvmaf`
```

As you can see, there are two `-L` arguments passed to the compiler while the `-l` argument is set to libvmaf

Comment: Your paths in the `rustc` command begin with /home/brandon while in the error the path starts with /home/me. I assume you wanted to hide the name of your directory and did not do it in every place, but just as a sanity check are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: @msaw328 yeah forgot I did that. I should probably change them back lol

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `lib` on the front of `libvmaf`? The `-l` option for C compilers generally add the `lib` prefix themselves - I am not sure if that is true of rustc as well, but worth a try

Comment: @harmic That worked! what a silly convention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On unix-like systems, compilers and linkers automatically add the `lib` suffix to the library names you provide via `-l`. Therefore you need your build.rs to emit:

```
cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=vmaf
```

There is a link modifier `verbatim` you can use to suppress this behaivour but it is [currently unstable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/native-link-modifiers-verbatim.html). In any case I would not recommend it - on unix-like systems the convention is that all libraries are prefixed with `lib` while this is not the case on Windows, so having the compiler automatically add the prefix according to platform is a good thing.